# __webpack_public_path__ in vite.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler, vite

Im trying achieve `__webpack_public_path__` equivalent using vite.js. To provide some context, using webpack I define the next variable in `public-path.js`. Then I make the build and upload the build to a server. The server then interpolates the content of the javascript and interpolate the `{{uuid}}` segment. it works as intented. It's needed for async import for codesplitting.

```js
__webpack_public_path__ = window['server-interpolate-{{uuid}}'];
```

But now I want to archieve the same using vite.js. I followed the config in https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html which seems to be the correct way to do it, but doesnt work; the final build doesnt contain any reference to the window variable previously defined. This is my vite.config file, when I put the console log I noticed that only HTML files are there. I mention again my usecase is with code splitting and async imports.

```js
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    manifest: false,
    // assetsDir: ".",
    minify: false,
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  experimental: {
    renderBuiltUrl(filename, { hostType, type, hostId, ssr }) {
      console.log('renderBuiltUrl', filename, hostType, type, hostId, ssr);
      if (hostType === 'js') {
        return { runtime: `window['server-interpolate-{{uuid}}']` }
      } else {
        return { relative: true }
      }
    }
  }
})
```